# Titanium - Hide keyboard

Tags: iphone, ios, titanium, appcelerator, event-listener

I am a beginner in Titanium Studio. I can able to hide the keyboard when a button is selected. It works,

```
okBtn.addEventListener("click", function(e) { textField.blur(); });
```

But, how can I hide the keyboard when I tap/click on the mapView? I tried this code, Doesn't work,

```
mapview.addEventListener("click", function(e) { textField.blur(); });

mapview.addEventListener("singletap", function(e) { textField.blur(); });
```

So, how can I make it work? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MapView only supports click events on annotations. That is why the click event is not firing in your use case.

(Note: The following JIRA ticket will clear up the documentation so that this is apparent: http://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TIMOB-4777 )

To be able to hide the keyboard when the user wants to interact with the map, you need to get a bit creative. Overlay a transparent view on the map view when the text field is focused, and hide it whenever the text field is blurred or the overlay is touched.

Does that make sense? It's a bit of a hack, to be sure, and I imagine it might be a bit disconcerting for your users. If you can explain the desired UX a bit more, I can probably provide a more desirable solution.